# getting incorrect rotation when trying to increment a sprite's zRotation by 1 degree with button press

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, gamekit

I have a simple rectangular sprite and want to rotate this sprite by 1 degree every time I press a button on screen. I have some simple code I expected to work but it's giving odd results. Instead of rotating the rectangle by 1 degree it seems to be rotating it by at least 180-270 degrees per tap.

```
var degrees = 0

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
    let beam = childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode


    if let body = physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation) {
        if body.node!.name == "leftTap" {
            print("Began touch on Left")
            beam.zRotation = CGFloat(degrees)
            degrees = degrees + 1

        }else{
            print("Began touch on right")
        }
    }
}
```

In the GameScene.sks sprite attribute inspector you can increment the rotation by pressing the "+" or "-" button. I figured this would work the same way, but I must not be understanding something about the rotation principals here.

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not degrees, it's rads. a value of 3 or so (pi) is a full spin.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483089-zrotation

Here is a handy extension you can use:

```
extension SKNode {
  // Usage is node.rotateBy(45) etc:
  func rotateBy(_ degree: CGFloat) {
    let conversionFactor = CGFloat(0.01745329252)
    self.run(.rotate(byAngle: degree * conversionFactor, duration: 0))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this! how come in the .sks I can increment by one degree?

Comment: @genericguy25 Haha, ask Apple. As you are seeing, this stuff wasn't necessarily designed perfectly ;)

Comment: @genericguy25 hold on a sec, let me make a func for you to help out

Comment: Thank you! How exactly would I use the extension? I haven't used many extensions before

Comment: @genericguy25 hold on a sec, I had a bug here.

Comment: @genericguy25 put this extension ANYWHERE at the top-level in your projects source code-- I personally like to make a file called "Utilities" or something like that.. then, you can use the functions ANYWHERE in your code. Now, any SKNode (to include labels, sprites, etc) can now call `.rotateBy`, as I pointed out in the comment

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it! I won't have a chance to try it out until tomorrow morning but ill let you know if I have any issues.